# Deploy all runtime artifacts from TravisCI to PyPi

Tags: travis-ci, pypi

I have a Python package that is cross-compiled against multiple Python runtimes (2.7, 3.3-6). I'm attempting to use TravisCI to build and deploy that package to PyPi. However, each runtime variant of a particular version tag produces an artifact of the same name: `mypackage-0.11.10.tar.gz`. As a result, PyPi only accepts the first runtime variant.

To reiterate: the *build* for a given version (say, `0.11.10`) succeeds in each runtime (`2.7`, `3.3`, ..., `3.6`), but each of these has the same artifact: `mypackage-0.11.10.tar.gz`. What I'd like to get to is something like `mypackage-0.11.10-py27.tar.gz`, or whatever might be appropriate.

It's possible I'm missing something, and I can be confident that if I have the build work against every runtime I'm good to go... but I lack that confidence, and don't know a good way to test it.

A sub-component of this is simply how to change the filename of the artifact being sent to PyPi by TravisCI? I was unable to determine if there was any way to do that.

This is my `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: python
python:
- '2.7'
- '3.3'
- '3.4'
- '3.5'
- '3.6'
- pypy
install:
- pip install coveralls
- pip install 'coverage<4'
script: nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=<my package name>
after_success:
- coveralls
deploy:
  provider: pypi
  user: <my pypi username>
  password:
    secure: <my encrypted pypi password>
  on:
    tags: true
    distributions: sdist bdist_wheel
    repo: <my repo>
    branch: production
```

Answer (score 0):

`.tar.gz` suggests it's a source distribution. You cannot have multiple source distributions for a version. But you can have many binary wheels, each one for a different Python version and architecture.